# Trying to increment by 1 in python but getting error about concatenating str and int

Tags: python, string, integer, concatenation

I am trying to increase order numbers by 1 each click, and declared order=1 and then a global variable. I keep getting an error:TypeError: can only concatenate str (not "int") to str and cannot figure out why. This is the code for the part I am referring to:

```
for order in prodplan:
    order += 1
```

Any ideas? thank you!!

Comment: can you post ``prodplan``

Comment: prodplan is an empty collection i am appending the value of order to

Comment: At each for loop `order` is changed with the next value of the iterator `prodplan`. So you overwrite global variable `order`.
In the for loop change order to another variable, e.g. `for x in prodplan:`

Comment: `order` seems to be a string(`str`). Post your full code & traceback

Comment: changing order variable in the for loop to x worked, thank you!!

Answer (score 0):

> and declared order=1 and then a global variable

This means you have declared order as a integer, Please correct me if i am wrong; I assume you have done something like this

```
order=1 #global scope
prodplan=["list of string values"]
for order in prodplan: #order defined again; local scope
     order += 1  # here the order is a string value, adding with integer will cause error
```

Since python has global variable scope and local scope; your error in declaring order in two places creates a confusion to the python interpreter. The right way might be

```
order=1
prodplan=["list of string values"]
for i in prodplan:
     order += 1  # here the order is a int value, adding with integer will be fine
```

by this way you might be able to get number of click as desired.